# CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 82

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encryption, game-development

Trying to implement Encryption/Decryption.. the way is to serialize the data into a JSON and then encrypting that JSON to save it. sometimes, it works without any issue while sometimes I get this bad padding error. is there anything that I am missing? tried switching to Rijndael but getting a similar exception.

**Save/Load Mechanics**

```
public static void SaveGameJson()
{

    Debug.Log("TRYING TO SAVE THE GMAE THROUGH Json File");
    SaveManager data = new SaveManager();

    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(data); // encrypting the json data..
//    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); // encrypting the json data..

    string encryptedJsonData = EncryptionRijndael.Encrypt(jsonData);
    WriteToFile(JsonfileName, encryptedJsonData);
    Debug.LogError("Json data Saved: " + jsonData);
    Debug.LogError("Json Encrypted data: " + encryptedJsonData);
}



public static SaveManager LoadGameJson()
{
    string path = GetFilePath(JsonfileName);
    Debug.Log("TRYING TO LOAD THE GMAE THROUGH FILE");

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        string encryptedJsonData = ReadFromFile(JsonfileName); // reading encrypted data from json Encrypted file
        string jsonData = EncryptionRijndael.Decrypt(encryptedJsonData); // decrypting json data from encrypted string
        Debug.LogError("Json data Load: " + jsonData);
        Debug.LogError("Encrypted Data: " + encryptedJsonData);
        SaveManager data = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveManager>(jsonData);
        //SaveManager data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SaveManager>(jsonData);

        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("save file not found on:" + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Additional Function**

```
    static void WriteToFile(string fileName, string json) {

    string path = GetFilePath(fileName);

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {
        writer.Write(json);
    }
}
```

**Encryption**

```
public static string Encrypt(string strPlain)
{
    string password = strPassword;
    if (!useSecure)
        return strPlain;

    try
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, GetIV(), Iterations);

        byte[] key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(8);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, des.CreateEncryptor(key, GetIV()), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            memoryStream.Write(GetIV(), 0, GetIV().Length);

            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPlain);

            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Encrypt Exception: " + e);
        return strPlain;
    }
}
```

**Decryption**

```
 public static string Decrypt(string strEncript)
 {

    string password = strPassword;

    if (!useSecure)
        return strEncript;

    try
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strEncript);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] iv = GetIV();
            memoryStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            // use derive bytes to generate key from password and IV
            var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, iv, Iterations);

            byte[] key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(8);

            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
            {
                string strPlain = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return strPlain;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Decrypt Exception: " + e);
        return strEncript;
    }
}
```

**JSON getting saved**
[image]

**Loading JSON from encrypted string**
[image]

PS: it seems like the encryption is working fine in the logs but when it tries to decrypt the string, it throughs this exception. Is there any better option for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my machine. Does the issue depend on the data, i.e. does it only occur for _specific_ data? Or does it also occur for the _same_ data sometimes and sometimes not?  Please post test data (password, IV, iteration, plaintext, ciphertext), the screenshots don't help that much. Irrelevant to the bug but still important: DES is insecure and was replaced by AES almost 20 years ago (which you should do as well).

Comment: Just edited the question with save/load code. I am using jsonutility to save the data into json and then encrypting it into a file.

Comment: Check (for the error case), if the keys for encryption and decryption are identical. Also check if `encryptedJsonData` in `string encryptedJsonData = EncryptionRijndael.Encrypt(jsonData)` and in `string encryptedJsonData = ReadFromFile(JsonfileName)` are identical (maybe there is an I/O error regarding the ciphertext).

Comment: I can' t reproduce the issue in .NET Core 3.1. This may be due to different implementations (according to the stacktrace you use Mono). [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1286146/systemsecuritycryptographycryptographicexception-b.html) might help.